# Imaging/Cloning Android phones and Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cloning

We are attempting to configure an Android phone with apps, etc and then create an Image so we can make many exact copies of this phone with all the configuration correct.

This works well, except we have found that Firebase Cloud Messaging thinks that Imaged phones are all the same phone and things get really messed up.

We have cleared the data for Google Play Services and our apps and forced stopped them all. This should of reset the GCM tokens, etc and created new ones but we are still having the issue.

How does Firebase Cloud Messaging create a device token (not app token) and how can we make the Imaging process work?

Comment: Hey mtopley. Just wanted to clarify the main issue here, by *device token*, do you mean the actual Android device or were you trying to point out a *registration token* (the one used by FCM)?

Comment: Hi AL. The actual Android device. We have 2 different registration tokens for 2 different devices but notifications go to both devices when it should only go to 1 device

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I don't have an idea on how the device token gets generated for Android, nor am I sure if the FCM token is tied to it somehow. Having different tokens should already let FCM know that it points to different devices. Could you post how you're sending the message and your sample payload?

Comment: Check out how to [Access the device registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) "*On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance. If you want to target single devices or create device groups, you'll need to access this token by extending [`FirebaseInstanceIdService`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService).*"

Comment: We have an extended FirebaseInstanceIdService to get the initial token and updated tokens. The 2 devices have different registration tokens but there must be some sort of device token in the userdata area of the device and our cloned devices have the same token since both devices receive the same notification.

Comment: We have many other devices which have been built manually and not clones and they operate as you'd expect.